# lost rvalue references if forward_as_tuple result is stored in variable before using it in std::apply

Tags: c++, tuples

While working on a project I encounter a situation std::apply does not forward rvalue references from `std::tuple` created by `std::forward_as_tuple *IF* resulting std::tuple` is stored in a variable! However if `std::forward_as_tuple`  result is not stored in a variable, but is just passed as a second argument to `std::apply` then it works and rvalue reference gets perfectly forwarded.

I tried many options including using different types for std::tuple, like

```
decltype(auto) t = forward_as_tuple(1, std::move(r))
auto t = forward_as_tuple(1, std::move(r))
auto&& t = forward_as_tuple(1, std::move(r))
auto& t = forward_as_tuple(1, std::move(r))
```

Nothing helped to store a tuple in a variable and then pass it to std::apply. It appears like lvalue reference being forwarded at the end to `std::__invoke` by `std::apply...`
There is a godbolt link to my code: https://godbolt.org/z/24LYP5

Code snippet

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

auto product(int l, int&& r) {  return l * r; }

static void test_not_works()
{
    int r = 2;
    decltype(auto) t = std::forward_as_tuple(1, std::move(r));
    std::apply(product, t);    
}

static void test_works()
{
    int r = 2;    
    std::apply(product, std::forward_as_tuple(1, std::move(r)));    
}
```

Error message

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/functional:54:0,

                 from <source>:1:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tuple: In instantiation of 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::__apply_impl(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&, std::index_sequence<_Idx ...>) [with _Fn = int (&)(int, int&&); _Tuple = std::tuple<int&&, int&&>&; long unsigned int ..._Idx = {0, 1}; std::index_sequence<_Idx ...> = std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0, 1>]':

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tuple:1671:31:   required from 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::apply(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&) [with _Fn = int (&)(int, int&&); _Tuple = std::tuple<int&&, int&&>&]'

<source>:10:26:   required from here

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tuple:1662:27: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(int (&)(int, int&&), int&, int&)'

       return std::__invoke(std::forward<_Fn>(__f),

              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

       std::get<_Idx>(std::forward<_Tuple>(__t))...);

       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tuple:41:0,

                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/functional:54,

                 from <source>:1:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h:89:5: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> constexpr typename std::__invoke_result<_Functor, _ArgTypes>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)

     __invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)

     ^~~~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> constexpr typename std::__invoke_result<_Functor, _ArgTypes>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (&)(int, int&&); _Args = {int&, int&}]':

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tuple:1662:27:   required from 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::__apply_impl(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&, std::index_sequence<_Idx ...>) [with _Fn = int (&)(int, int&&); _Tuple = std::tuple<int&&, int&&>&; long unsigned int ..._Idx = {0, 1}; std::index_sequence<_Idx ...> = std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0, 1>]'

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tuple:1671:31:   required from 'constexpr decltype(auto) std::apply(_Fn&&, _Tuple&&) [with _Fn = int (&)(int, int&&); _Tuple = std::tuple<int&&, int&&>&]'

<source>:10:26:   required from here

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h:89:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::__invoke_result<int (&)(int, int&&), int&, int&>'

Compiler returned: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::apply` perfect-forwards the tuple to `std::get` to access elements of the tuple. `std::get` returns an lvalue reference if its tuple argument is an lvalue. Since your `t` variable is an lvalue, `std::apply` calls `product` with an `int&` instead of an `int&&`.

I can't speak for the motivation behind having it work this way despite the tuple explicitly holding an rvalue reference. However, a simple way to get the same behaviour as a temporary here is to use `std::move` to produce an xvalue, which will handle stored references in the way you want:

```
std::apply(product, std::move(t));
```

Note, however, that unlike using just `t`, any non-reference types in the tuple should now be treated as moved from. I'm unsure if there's a simple way to both use the tuple's reference types and treat non-reference types as lvalues for an lvalue tuple. Granted this won't be an issue when creating the tuple using `forward_as_tuple` since it will always contain references.

Comment: "std::get returns an lvalue reference if its tuple argument is an lvalue" - is a key. Thanks! Yeah, this motivation is a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: @minex, Perhaps it's to model the tuple as a bunch of variables. People get surprised the first time they see that `int&&r = ...; f(r);` won't call `f(int&&)`. It might be meant to work the same here, pretending you actually have a bunch of variables and one is an rvalue reference.

Comment: template< class T, class... Types >
constexpr T& get(tuple<Types...>& t) noexcept;
(5) (since C++14)
template< class T, class... Types >
constexpr T&& get(tuple<Types...>&& t) noexcept . Oh seems like refrence coallascing does the trick here and it is std::get feature! Since for int&& would be deduced to int and if tuple lvalue is passed it would become lvalue ref!

Comment: But I see your point on their motivation to treat tuple merely as a list of variables with some context.

Answer (score 3):

When rvalue references are passed to `std::forward_as_tuple`, it constructs a `std::tuple` of rvalue references. So first of all, declaring `t` as `auto t = std::forward_as_tuple(...)`  is fine, the "rvalueness"  of the object is encoded inside the type generated by `std::forward_as_tuple`.

But then note that there is something special about the first argument to `std::apply`: `product` takes an `int` parameter by value, and a second one as `int&&`, i.e., an rvalue-reference. Calling such a function obviously requires the second argument to be an rvalue reference, but this does only work if you make sure it is one. Hence:

```
auto t = std::forward_as_tuple(1, std::move(r));
std::apply(product, std::move(t));
                   // ^^^^^^^ cast to rvalue here
```

Another possible fix is to change `product` to accept to plain `int`s by value (in case of an `int`, there is no performance hit anyway). Then, you can pass `t` as an lvalue, too.

Comment: This is tricky! Thanks for the fast response! But why cannot std::apply perfectly forward the second argument even from by lvalue refrence passed tuple if tuple itself contains rvalue refrences. That is where I am confused. Why tuple itself would need to be rvalue refrence.

Comment: `std::apply` does do perfect forwarding, but in the function you posted, `t` was an lvalue, to perfect forwarding preserves its lvalue-ness... that's the point of perfect forwarding: let lvalues be lvalues and let rvalues continue to be rvalues.

Comment: perfect forwarding can demote xvalue to lvalue for the items contained in the composite type (like tuple) if the composite type itself is lvalue? Or this is just a feature of std::get?

Comment: Once an rvalue has been bound to a name, it's an lvalue again, whether it's a wrapping type as `std::tuple` or rvalue references or a plain rvalue reference.

Comment: Right. But what is mind-blowing here is that it propagates even to aggregated values!

Comment: template< class T, class... Types > constexpr T& get(tuple<Types...>& t) noexcept; (5) (since C++14) template< class T, class... Types > constexpr T&& get(tuple<Types...>&& t) noexcept . Oh seems like refrence coallascing does the trick here and it is std::get feature! Since for int&& would be deduced to int and if tuple lvalue is passed it would become lvalue ref!